# Elasticsearch terms case-insensitive performance

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, case-insensitive, elasticsearch-8

I'm using ES 8.7 and 8.8, and considering about 2 searching scenarios:

- Indexing without lowercase normalizer and write terms query with case-insensitive is true
- Indexing with lowercase normalize and write terms query with lowercase value

I'm searching a bit in google about searching performance comparison or best practices recommendations. Also searching in ES doc
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html

So i ask this question to find the better searching approach.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you thinking about index-time or search-time performance? How do you define "better approach" in your context/use case?